# Magento : How to get full product URL using category

Tags: magento

I am trying to find a solution for making sure that Magento always shows the complete URL of every product including the category path.
I want the complete url to also be there in search results also.
For this i have put every product in only one category.

Can this be done by Url Rewrite custom through magento?
Is 301 redirect using .htaccess, for /product.html to category/subcategory/product.html a good idea?

Thanks 
Moody

Answer (score 4):

What we do to get full category in products url is using a helper that'll try to get you a product URL with the category. You could also rewrite the product method but its kind of a pain whenever another module rewrites some product stuff, this is why we use the helper approach.

Here's our method:

```
public static function getFullUrl (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product , 
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category = null , 
        $mustBeIncludedInNavigation = true ){

    // Try to find url matching provided category
    if( $category != null){
        // Category is no match then we'll try to find some other category later
        if( !in_array($product->getId() , $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds() ) 
                ||  !self::isCategoryAcceptable($category , $mustBeIncludedInNavigation )){
            $category = null;
        }
    }
    if ($category == null) {
        if( is_null($product->getCategoryIds() )){
            return $product->getProductUrl();
        }
        $catCount = 0;
        $productCategories = $product->getCategoryIds();
        // Go through all product's categories
        while( $catCount < count($productCategories) && $category == null ) {
            $tmpCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($productCategories[$catCount]);
            // See if category fits (active, url key, included in menu)
            if ( !self::isCategoryAcceptable($tmpCategory , $mustBeIncludedInNavigation ) ) {
                $catCount++;
            }else{
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($productCategories[$catCount]);
            }
        }
    }
    $url = (!is_null( $product->getUrlPath($category))) ?  Mage::getBaseUrl() . $product->getUrlPath($category) : $product->getProductUrl();
    return $url;
}

/**
 * Checks if a category matches criteria: active && url_key not null && included in menu if it has to
 */
protected static function isCategoryAcceptable(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category = null, $mustBeIncludedInNavigation = true){
    if( !$category->getIsActive() || is_null( $category->getUrlKey() )
        || ( $mustBeIncludedInNavigation && !$category->getIncludeInMenu()) ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If a category is specified it tries to get a url relative to this one.

If no category is specified or couldn't find a url with provided one, the method tries to get the product URL relative to the first category that the product is attached to, and checks if it's acceptable (active, with a url key and matching navigation criteria).

Finally if it falls back to original `$product->getProductUrl()` Magento method.

You'll have to use it in templates (categories, cart products, recently viewed etc....) with this call :

```
echo $this->helper('yourcompany/yourmodule')::getFullProductUrl($_product);
```

**Edit:**

I took Zachary's remarks into account and tweaked it up a little by adding some checks and options. Hope it's cool now.
Examples :

```
echo $this->helper('yourcompany/yourmodule')::getFullProductUrl($_product, $aCategory);
```

will try to find a product url in $aCategory then fall back to other category urls and finally product base url

```
echo $this->helper('yourcompany/yourmodule')::getFullProductUrl($_product, someCategory, false);
```

will also consider categories that are not included in navigation.

Comment: I use something similar, but one mistake you are making is that you are assuming that getUrlPath() is going to return a value. It doesn't always in some cases. You also cannot depend on a category having a url key, unfortunately. You have to do a check to make sure the category has one first before using it in the $url declaration. (If it doesn't, iterate to next category)

Comment: Thats true. Thanks for the input i'll modify the answer soon!

Comment: thanks guys for ur feedback... will try to implement it as soon as possible. Thanks again..

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I am currently having an issue implementing this solution in magento 1.8 and I am not sure why. my local magento copy version is 1.7 and it works fine there but in 1.8 the url returned breaks in category pages and no matter what category you are on it returns just the base category with no product name. (ex: `mysite/base-category`) and in product pages it always returns just the base category and no subs. (ex: `mysite/base-category/item.html`)