# SEO: category and product path (URL) - Magento

Tags: magento, url, seo

I have one or two categries in magento but these are not always showing up in URL.

**Example:**

When I navigate to a product page the path looks like this:

```
.../cat/subcat/product.html
```

However, when I click a product directly from the frontpage (newest, featured), then the URL structure looks like this:

```
.../product.html
```

My first thought was to deactivate, that the category is showing up within the URL (backend seo tab).

Well, I'm trying to `seo` the shop and not very happy with this solution. I'd like to have always a clear structured URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846195/magento-how-to-get-full-product-url-using-category

Comment: This might be a good approach thx laxonline. I wonder why this has been developed in this way. Does it have influence for search engine optimization? I thought the structure would be very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website has a complicated structure, you will have multiply URL for a single product, just like you mentioned. This situation may damage your website's profile to the customer, but it won't be any problems to Search Engine. The latest version of Magento provides canonical URL support for product and category. You may access the configuration under

System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Canonical Like Meta Tag for Products

If you are going to eliminate this situation throughly, you can create URL writes to the URL you want through a 403 status code, which also will tell search engine that the content has been permanently migrate to the target URL and user can only access the URL you want to present to them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that a product can belong to multiple categories so what category should be used in this case?
Depending on how you are outputting the newest, featured etc.. you could use a static block instead and simply put in the products manually which you can then link to the product in the category you want. This is a manual process but one that would work for what you want to do without requiring custom work.
Cheers
Adam

Comment: Hey Adam, thx for your help. The output is handled by the theme we've purchased: http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/default/

As you can see there are these newest products as well. These products have a connection to a simple category with an id.

Output example:

{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" category_id="13" product_count="15" is_random="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Top Products" template="/catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml"}}